# Log in twice via Idhttp

Tags: delphi-7, basic-authentication, idhttp

I have placed an Idhttp component on my main form and an IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and both components are not adjusted via the IDE. I use it to access two servers:

1) A http server which requires an authentication;

2) A https-server (which requires an authentication).

When I connect via Idhttp to server (1) I can connect via a regular fashion. However, when I connect to server (2) it returns a message that the user credentials are not correct.

I tried switching the procedures but then I cannot login into server (1): I get in both situations the response from the server that I input wrong credentials.

I presume some property is changed. I checked the Idhttp.Request.UserName and  Idhttp.Request.Password before I connect and they are correct.

What is going wrong?

```
procedure TForm1.AccessServer1;
var  
  fs: TMemoryStream
begin  
  fs := TMemoryStream.Create;
  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := true;
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserName := myUsername1;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Password := MyPassword1;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get(myURL1, fs);
    fs.SaveToFile(MyFilename);
  finally
    fs.free
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.AccessServer2;
var  
  fs: TMemoryStream
begin  
  fs := TMemoryStream.Create;
  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := true;
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserName := myUsername2;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Password := MyPassword2;
  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP1.IOHandler := AIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get(myURL2, fs);
    fs.SaveToFile(MyFilename);
  finally
    fs.free
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to both at the same time? Or are you closing one connection and then attempting open the other? If you just try to connect to the secure server, what happens?

Comment: Authentication is ultimately handled by the `TIdHTTP.Request.Authentication` property, so check if it is carrying over any incorrect credentials from one connection to the other.

Comment: @Dsm: No, I am connecting to one closing it and then connecting to the second.

To Remy: Only the username and password are relevant  of the TIdHTTP.Request.Authentication property, right?

Comment: Have you a valid correct SSL certificate? SSL is more than just user/password.

Comment: Well it logs in and connects if I only connect to server (1) or server (2).